# Least squares with multiple outputs but one coefficient per example

Tags: regression, machine-learning, classification, optimization, ensemble-learning

According to Elements of Statistical Learning Ch 8.8, we can apply least sqaures at the population level to show that for a regression ensemble $f_1(x), f_2(x), \ldots , f_M(x)$ where $f_j: \mathbb{R}^p \to \mathbb{R}$ the full ensemble has smaller error than any single model:

$$ \mathbb{E}[y - \sum_{j=1}^{M}\hat{w}_jf_j(x)]^2 \leq \mathbb{E}[y - f_j(x)]^2 \hspace{0.25cm} \forall \hspace{0.25cm} j.$$

Where this is shown my simply solving the standard least squares problem that

$$ \hat{w} = \mathop{\arg \min}\limits_w \mathbb{E} [ y - \sum_{j=1}^{M} w_{j} f_{j}(x) ] ^2. $$

Suppose now we are interested in the multi-class problem where $y \in \mathbb{R}^k$ and $f(x) \in \mathbb{R}^p$ but we still have only $M$ weights $w_1, \ldots, w_M$. Does an equivalent result hold? Could one derive a similar result for *average* least squares or negative log likelihood losses?